# W3c Validator for php

Tags: w3c-validation

I am applying my php file for w3 validation. While doing the same i got an error "Sorry! This document can not be checked." is there any specific reason behind this?

Comment: Do you get any response at all? Sometimes this can happen when the document contains characters not corresponding to the encoding set in the header.

Answer (score 0):

http://validator.w3.org/ is only for (X)HTML (and some other markup languages), not PHP (which is an programming language).

> Check the markup (HTML, XHTML, …) of Web documents

You'd have to run the PHP file (on your server) to get the HTML output and paste that into the validator.